# Rewrite subdomain to a folder and redirect that folder to a subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have rewrite rule that sends all users from `random.example.com` to `/random/`

But I want to make it so that IF a user was to directly visit `/random/` it would redirect (redirect NOT rewrite) them to the subdomain.

This is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine on  
# NO WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# USE RANDOM SUB DOMAIN WITH CONTENT IN SUB FOLDER
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} random.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/random
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /random/$1 [L]

# SEND SNOOPERS AT SUB FOLDER TO SUB
Redirect ^(.*)$/random/$1 %{HTTP_HOST}random.example.com$
```

However, I get a server 500 error for that last line. Basically it needs to handle any urls that come through on the random directory, so for example:

```
http://example.com/random -> http://random.example.com/

http://example.com/random/fakeplace/ -> http://random.example.com/fakeplace/

http://example.com/random?id=4 -> http://random.example.com/?id=4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong with the last line. You are even mixing RewriteRule with Redirect. Try these rules. I changed a few things.

```
RewriteEngine on  
# NO WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# USE RANDOM SUB DOMAIN WITH CONTENT IN SUB FOLDER
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^random\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !^random/? random%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/random/([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://random.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I would think you would need the slash prefix on the 2nd `RewriteRule` substitution? (Or provide a `RewriteBase /` directive.)

Comment: @w3d thanks but it _shouldn't_ be required because `random` is relative to the document root.